# Adding filter to each column of jqgrid

Tags: javascript, search, filter, jqgrid

I have a `jqgrid` that shows details of employees and i would like to add a filter in each column using which a user can type in company name and the grid shows all the employee rows that matches that filter in the grid.

Googled alot but no success. Any refrence examples/link will help.

Comment: did you check the `toolbar search` functionality?

Comment: This link is also having the verified solution.. Short and Sweet Solution - http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_28462507.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use filterToolbar option when you type the name of test case in the text box you data will fiter through the records, here is the code and working [example demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uQQn3/1/)

```
 var mydata = [
    {id:"1",invdate:"2010-05-24",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"2111.00"} ,
    {id:"2",invdate:"2010-05-25",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
    {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
    {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"blah",note:"stuff",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},

];
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
data: mydata,
datatype: "local",
height: 150,
rowNum: 10,
rowList: [10,20,30],
   colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
   colModel:[
       {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
       {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"},
       {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
       {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number"},
       {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},        
       {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},        
       {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}        
   ],
   pager: "#pager",
   viewrecords: true,
   autowidth: true,
   height: 'auto',
   caption: "Test Grid"
});

jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });



<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```